# Плагин fidvids не работает с Facebook

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Пытаюсь настроить плагин `fidvids` для WordPress. Плагин растягивает видео из различных соцсетей по ширине экрана. И если с Youtube все хорошо, то с Facebook отказывается работать.
Полазил в интернете, нашел пример работы этого плагина с Facebook:
[Пример](https://codepen.io/davatron5000/pen/bZWrbr?editors=1010)
Проблема в том, что если в примере элемент:

```
 <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FEQHQLivingston%2Fvideos%2Fvb.57422952903%2F10153960325327904%2F%3Ftype%3D3&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

То у меня на сайте он следующий:

```
 <iframe name="f2a1c02642868ec" width="500px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:video Facebook Social Plugin" src="https://www.facebook.com/v2.11/plugins/video.php?app_id=&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FlY4eZXm_YWu.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df7211707bc33e%26domain%3Dheroine.lc%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fheroine.lc%252Ff1c6c92b14281f%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=806&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fthatsharassment%2Fvideos%2F1653469821334026%2F&amp;locale=ru_RU&amp;sdk=joey&amp;width=500" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 500px; height: 280px;" class=""></iframe>
```

И ничего не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, у фейсбука очень серьезное отношение к публикации своих ссылок, есть целый гайд с нормами, которые нужно реализовывать и соблюдать.
Сайт на Wordpress и ссылки с facebook открываются и публикуются через их плейер, ширина которого никоим образом не менялась.
Даже если править страничку через веб редактор, сразу же меняло обратно...
Но как оказалось, iframe хранился в теге div класса `fb-video` и атрибутом `data-width = "500"` Вот как раз изменение этого атрибута до 1000 и спасло положение...
Сама верстка видео резиновая, поэтому большое значение уменьшилось до границ сайта и мобильная версия не пострадала.

Answer (score 0):

Как видно у Вас в src есть параметр app_id, и он пуст, я полагаю что для данного плагина нужно регистрировать приложение на фейсбук, посмотрите также что в консоли.

Ещё вариант решения: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-with-facebook-video-embeds/